# Elements with display: none are printing to sheet.

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, highcharts

Im having some trouble getting this to work I have a complex HTML page that has a chart(from Highcharts) which when I try to print just the chart, prints the chart plus the page which has all elements set to display: none. This is a module from highcharts.

```
print: function () {
    // win.print();
    var chart = this,
        container = chart.container,
        origDisplay = [],
        origParent = container.parentNode,
        body = doc.body,
        childNodes = body.childNodes;

    if (chart.isPrinting) { // block the button while in printing mode
        return;
    }

    chart.isPrinting = true;

    // hide all body content
    each(childNodes, function (node, i) {
        if (node.nodeType === 1) {
            origDisplay[i] = node.style.display;
            node.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });

    // pull out the chart
    body.appendChild(container);

    // print
    win.focus(); // #1510
    win.print();



    // allow the browser to prepare before reverting
    setTimeout(function () {

        // put the chart back in
        origParent.appendChild(container);

        // restore all body content
        each(childNodes, function (node, i) {
            if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                node.style.display = origDisplay[i];
            }
        });

        chart.isPrinting = false;

    }, 1000);
},
```

I don't know why this is not working. [Here](http://hastebin.com/fihoyiyihi.xml) is a link to my page source code.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you set the css file type to print/screen?

Comment: @Jessica Im not using different css files. If you look at the code the display of the elements its being set to none in the first loop.

Comment: Maybe you have some `display: block !important` set? Could you reproduce issue on jsFiddle? Demos from Highcharts.com works fine.